# Nginx: do something if the upstream response size is larger than a threshold

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) as a reverse proxy for different sites and I need to do something different when the clients try to download a large file.

How can I check for this and act as I need.

P.S) Does `$upstream_response_length` show the combined file size?

P.S) How can I check if it is larger than for example 10MB?

Thanks

Comment: My problem is that I am using [modsecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/tree/nginx_refactoring) with nginx with directive `ModSecurity On` and it drains the cpu for large file downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a piece of lua code that will handle proxy request for you.

Or you can just pass the request to the backend and do something on log_by_lua.

Depends on what you want to accieve.

Comment: I had a glance at [Lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and it seem fascinating. But also complicated and hard to understand rapidly, can you tell me please if I can turn off a module for download files larger than 10 MB. My problem is that I am using [modsecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/tree/nginx_refactoring) with nginx with directive `ModSecurity On` and it drains the cpu for large file downloads. Can I use lua and somehow apply `ModSecurity Off` when the client download size exceeds 10 MB?